# Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs' while installing react native

Tags: react-native

for the past couple of days now, I've been trying to install react native using npx react-native init AppName, and since then I've been getting this error. I've searched the net and couldn't get a better answer to this problem, how do i go about solving it?

node:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;

  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\gracefulifyFs.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at _gracefulFs (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\gracefulifyFs.js:19:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\gracefulifyFs.js:30:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\tools\\gracefulifyFs.js',
    'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\bin.js'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

```
sudo npm install
```

solved it for me.

Comment: I've done this many times and it did not work. Plus I can't use the sudo command because I'm using Windows os not Mac.